# Why does the Law of Sines give an external angle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does the Law of Sines give the exterior angle below:

[image]

I am fully aware that the Law of Sines can be used in the following way:

$\dfrac{\sin 20}{250}=\dfrac{\sin \theta}{500}\implies \theta\approx 45^{\circ}$, and this angle should be the angle opposite to $500$m, but for some reason it is supposed to be the exterior angle. Can anyone explain why?

Also, in case it is relevant, this question stems from the original problem:

> A small lighthouse is on a man made island just offshore. The light can illuminate effectively up to a distance of $250$ meters. From a point along the shore that is $500$ meters from the lighthouse, the sightline to the lighthouse makes an angle of $20^{\circ}$ with the shoreline. What length (to the nearest meter) of the shoreline is effectively illuminated by the light from the lighthouse?

Comment: In general, the sine of $x$ and the sine of $180^\circ -x$ are the same. So the Law of Sines doesn't care whether you want the external or internal angle. You need to choose between $x$ and 4180^\circ -x$ from additional information.

Comment: Your error is in assuming that $\dfrac{\sin 20}{250}=\dfrac{\sin \theta}{500}\implies \theta\approx 45^{\circ}$. You can conclude that $\sin\theta\approx0.684$, but that doesn't determine the value of $\theta$. There are two possible values of $\theta$ between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$, and you need to see what the solutions tell you about the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem does involve the Ambiguous Case;  one in which you are given two sides of a triangle, and an angle ***not*** between those two sides.  Depending on the exact values given, there may be two solutions, one solution (for two different reasons) or no solution.  This is the case, ***no matter how the problem is solved***.

As others have noted correctly, your use of the Law of Sines is one way to solve this problem, as long as you recognize that the inverse sine function gives only one of the two possible angles.  The other possible solution is $(180^\circ -\theta)$,   Then use each of these angles in turn to solve for two values of the third side.

Another, quicker way to solve this problem is to use the Law of Cosine to find the two values of the base directly.  Applying the Law of Cosines, with $y$ equal to the shoreline side:$$250^2=500^2+y^2-2\cdot500 \cdot y\cdot \cos(20^\circ )$$The difference between the two solutions to this quadratic is the desired $x$

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity with the Law of Sines under a particular case. And that case is exactly what happens in your problem I believe. Have a look at the "The ambiguous case" paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines.